# Remove column in linkki-Table

Tags: linkki

I have an existing TablePmo and TableRowPmo. The TableRowPmo contains three columns:

```
@UITableColumn
@UIMoneyField(...)
public String getOne()

@UITableColumn
@UIMoneyField(...)
public String getTwo()

@UITableColumn
@UIMoneyField(...)
public String getThree()
```

I can't edit neither the TablePmo nor the TableRowPmo, but I need to hide the middle column. So I created ReducedTableRowPmo extends TableRowPmo and have overwritten the method getTwo and tried the following (none with the desired effect, the middle column gone):

- @UITableColumn(width=0)
- @UIMoneyField(... visible = VisibleType.INVISIBLE ...)
- Removed @UITableColumn annotation ReducedTableRowPmo

What is the correct way to hide a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns are created before any instance of row items is created. That means table columns are static. Just imagine: which row instance should be used if the table is empty of if there are multiple row instances of different subtypes?

That means: linkki have to use the type provided by the `ContainerPmo`, in your example the `TablePmo`. In `ContainerPmo` there is a method called `getItemPmoClass()`. This is the type that is used to create the table columns. Only way to have different table columns is to provide another type using this method. Hence you have to change your `TablePmo`.

Comment: I've overwritten the `getItemPmoClass()` to return my `ReducedTableRowPmo.class`, but there is no change in behavior, none of the changes mentioned above showed the desired effect.
Is this because ReducedTableRowPmo extends TableRowPmo?